# Forward messages in twilio programable chat

Tags: java, android, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I have integrated Twilio's programmable chat in my application now I want to forward the same messages that I have in my one channel to another channel.
is there a way to do so?

I know I can create a new message with the data in this message and then send it. but I don't want to reupload the media.

Comment: Have you looked at [`<Redirect>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml/redirect)? The URL could be the next channel you want to forward to. Don't know your setup so don't know if this is applicable/would work.

Comment: @yvesonline I am not using Twilio Programmable Messaging I am using Twilio Programmable chat, and they both are different

Comment: Oops, sorry, it's mentioned three times and I still got it wrong. So you can use the approach described [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/media-support?code-sample=code-creating-a-media-message&code-language=Android%20-%20Java&code-sdk-version=default#sending-a-media-message) then? First upload to MCS and then reference the media via `MediaSid`.